# Remove/disable Image Rendition Selection when adding a picture to a custom Content Type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is it possible to remove/disable the selection of the Image Rendition when selecting a picture in a custom content type?

Any User/Contributer should **not** be able to choose the image Rendition because it happens programmatically in the Display Template. The Picture must always be choosen as Full Size Image!
Has anyone an idea how i can set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i remember Image Renditions are implemented using query string params so you can always ignore provided by user image rendition and override it in your display template.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the picture in the Item_Custom.html Template (masterpages\Display Templates\Cotrol Web Parts\Item_Custom.html) like I did in the other Templates:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">&#39;Category Image&#39;{Category Image}:&#39;MyCategoryImageOWSIMGE&#39;,&#39; .... </mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

Then Set the JS Variable:

```
<!--#_
    var CategoryImage = $getItemValue(ctx, "Category Image");
_#-->
```

And manually set the Rendition ID, no matter what was choosen by the user:

```
<img style="visibility: visible;" src="_#= CategoryImage =#_?RenditionID=7" id="CategoryImage" onload ... >
```